# VLOOKUP not understanding numbers

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup

I had this same problem on Excel and Google Sheets.

In cell D2 I have this number:

```
1172000180
```

This number is the result of a function, that looks like this:

```
=text(substitute(substitute(substitute(SUBSTITUTE(C2;".";"");"/";"");"-";"");":";"");"#######################")
```

I'm trying to run VLOOKUP in a table:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2;blacklist!B1:C15538;2;FALSE)
```

The table looks like this:

```
Index   Code            Name
6136    3758336000106   GRAFINORTE S/A.
7719    95420188000133  EDITORA JORNAL DE BELTRAO S A
86851   1172000180      SA CORREIO BRAZILIENSE
50716   10798130000175  EDITORA JORNAL DO COMMERCIO S.A
169806  10803492000107  DIARIO DE PERNAMBUCO SA
...
```

The result I'm getting is `#N/A`.

Comment: It sounds like a formatting issue---trying to do a VLOOKUP from a text string to a number field.  Can you format the columns the same?

Comment: What columns is `Index`, `Code`, `Name`? Is `Code` column formatted as text or as a number? I'd guess the problem is your `text()` function

Comment: Try using `Trim`?

Comment: Try it with `=--text(...` In other words `1172000180 <> "1172000180"`

Comment: @radiocontrolled was right. it was a formatting issue. I did =text(...) * 1, it understood it was definitely a number and it worked